# How to store a specific time that a signal value is changed in another parameter in Matlab simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have two Matlab function blocks that one is producing zero signal for the other. I want to store the exact time that signal changes to one in another parameter in order to use it elsewhere.
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide more information? And maybe add some screenshots of the relevant parts of your Simulink diagram. Thanks.

Comment: You can't (or more correctly don't want to) store it as a **parameter** (which is something entered into a dialog box), but can create a **signal** with the value in it (which can be fed into another block as an input.)  Is that what you asking about?

Comment: @PhilGoddard Yes, I think that's what I want. how it could be done to extract the exact time as an input signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of functinality is achieved using a `Triggered Subsystem`, as per the image below,

[image: Triggered Latch]

The output of the trigger block will take on value of the input (which in this case is the simulation time) every time the trigger signal rises.  Look at the parameters of the `Trigger` block inside the subsystem for other options such as falling edge, or both edge, triggering.